# Outlier in GEE ERA5 daily aggregate: Extreme values of v component of wind 10m on one day?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have been working on calculating the average wind speeds for specific areas over a period of time using the ERA5 Daily aggregates data set. However, I have encountered a significant problem with the results, as the averages I obtained were absurdly high, often around 1E24.

Upon further investigation, I believe I have identified a potential mistake in the dataset. It appears that on the date 2009-07-14, the v-component of wind speed contains extreme values, ranging from 1E-20 to 1E35.

Also, I noticed that values more north than 75 degrees seem unaffected.

For reference, here is the link to a script that displays the problem:  https://code.earthengine.google.com/7334d4658fe0002ee17980a9ca8dde80

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue and obtain reliable average wind speed calculations. Of course I could remove the outlier.

Should I report the error somewhere?

P.S. as I am a beginner GEE user, so could be that I made rookie mistake.

```
    var ERA5Daily = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY");        
    var normalDay = ERA5Daily
     .filterDate('2009-07-15')
     .first()
     .select('v_component_of_wind_10m')
    
    var visNormal = {
      min:0,
      max:12,
      palette: ['white', 'black']
    }
    
    Map.addLayer(normalDay, visNormal, 'normalday')
    
    var outlier = ERA5Daily.filterDate('2009-07-14')
     .first()
     .select('v_component_of_wind_10m')
        
    var vis = {
      min: 0,
      max: 1E38,
      palette: ["white", "black"]
    }
    
    Map.addLayer(outlier, vis, 'outlierday')
```